# VSCODE & GitHub Desktop pre-commit hook: npx: command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-desktop, husky, lint-staged

I am starting a new repo, thinking I should use the most recent Huksy v6 which is installed from LintStaged using their setup guide:

```
npx mrm lint-staged

// package.json updated with:
"husky": ">=6",
"lint-staged": ">=10",
```

This adds necessary packages and adds the husky files including the precommit files:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

When i run my commit in the terminal it works fine.  However, if I try to run my commit in GitHub Desktop or VSCode (which I know some teammates do), it results in an error for both:

> npx: command not found.  husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)

I have npx installed:

```
npx -v
// 6.14.10
```

If I try to install in globall, such as described in other StackOverflow suggestions, it returns a warning about existing location (with & with out `sudo`):

> ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/npx/index.js' -> '/Users/plucks/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/npx'
> npm ERR! File exists: /Users/plucks/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/npx
> npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
> npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

Is there anything I can do so the programs like VSCode & GitHub Desktop can run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to combine the answers of Cathal and Misol.

I did not want to edit the `.husky/pre-commit` like Cathal for two reasons:

1. I would need to that for every project I use husky in
2. It would actually break husky for my fellow developers on Windows

So I added a global `~/.huskyrc` file like Misol did with the following contents:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
. "$(dirname $NVM_DIR)/nvm.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
a=$(nvm ls | grep 'node')
b=${a#*(-> }
v=${b%%[)| ]*}

export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$v/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, very nice.

Comment: this is the only solution which worked for both VSCode & Github Desktop for me

Comment: where you added this file which directory

Comment: As mentioned in my answer it's in the home folder. That what tilde (`~`) means. You can read more about that here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Answer (score 92):

I've got the solution from here. Hope you can find it as well!

- https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=command-not-found
- https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/912

Here it is, for clarity:

- add a file `~/.huskyrc` if you don't have one already
- make sure it includes the following:

```
# ~/.huskyrc
# This loads nvm.sh and sets the correct PATH before running hook
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: Prefer to add this into .husky/pre-commit because you can share it via git

Answer (score 43):

Before adding any modifications to your project try restarting your IDE as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/912#issuecomment-968512407)

Comment: I highly recommend other people try this first. This worked for me and saved a lot of hassle of not having to write a bunch of bash scripting or custom configuring.

Comment: Yes restarting fixed it for me as well, it was working fine for me with VS Code and started breaking for me all of a sudden, I tried reloading the window that didn't work out but if you restart the IDE that fixes it.

Comment: This response should be on the top! Thanks sir, I was about to go crazy on this issue!

Comment: I had this issue with GitHub Desktop on macOS after updating xcode, and restarting it fixed it for me as well.

Comment: LOL. This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

As per [this suggestion](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/912#issuecomment-817522060), adding the following to your `pre-commit` file should fix it:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
. "$(dirname $NVM_DIR)/nvm.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
a=$(nvm ls | grep 'node')
b=${a#*(-> }
v=${b%%[)| ]*}

export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$v/bin:$PATH"
```

So the full file would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
. "$(dirname $NVM_DIR)/nvm.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
a=$(nvm ls | grep 'node')
b=${a#*(-> }
v=${b%%[)| ]*}

export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$v/bin:$PATH"

npm run test
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm running Ubuntu and added that first block of text to ~/.huskyrc and fixed the issue when doing a commit from GitHub Desktop.

Comment: what if you dont use nvm?

Answer (score 17):

For `husky>=6`: update your `.husky/pre-commit` file to contain this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

This will find and expose the current `node` path and therefore `npx` path that you are using, which has been configured with Node Version Manager `nvm`

Answer (score 3):

For those using [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) instead of `nvm`, adding the following to `~/.huskyrc` worked for me:

```bash
eval "$(fnm env)"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a team with other people who may have installed nvm or node in slightly different fashion than you have, I would not recommend adding any export statements or edits to the `$PATH` in your `.husky/precommit` or `~/.huskyrc` files.

If you want your VSCode to have proper access to the `$PATH` you expect from terminal you should always launch VSCode from terminal in the folder you are working from.

For example, in a terminal window:

```
~/_git/my_project: code .
```

Will launch VSCode with `my_project` open in a new window (it should remember your tabs and window state from the last time you worked on your project).

VSCode will now use the `$PATH` your terminal uses from your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, etc.

With this setup my `.husky/precommit` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

and my my `.lintstagedrc.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
    "eslint --fix --debug --max-warnings=-1",
    "npm run lint:prettier-fix"
  ],
  "*.{css,less,sass,scss}": ["npm run lint:prettier-fix"],
  "*.{g?(raph)ql,json,html,md,y?(a)ml}": ["npm run lint:prettier-fix"]
}
```

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. People aren't going to only ever launch VSCode and Github Desktop via CLI from a project folder.

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions are fine until you have only one node version if you have two node versions and in one of them you don't have the **yarn**, you will face this issue,
so do a simple change

```
# ~/.huskyrc
# This loads nvm.sh and sets the correct PATH before running hook
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# This take the current active node version you want to verify the hook
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
a=$(nvm current)

export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$a/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open VSCode settings and set the Inherit Env setting (*Terminal > Integrated: Inherit Env*) to false:

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

This setting enables or disables whether new shells should inherit their environment from VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I change code as the top answer says. But it doesn't works at first, and then reopen VScode and it works.

In the terminal, I input these commands:

1. copy this command in terminal and press enter.

`vi ~/.huskyrc`

2. copy this command in terminal.

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

3. input `:wq` to quit edit state
4. reopen VScode.