# Committing the yarn.lock File with Specified Versions in package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, hadoop-yarn, pnpm

Is it a good practice to consistently commit the yarn.lock file, considering that all versions are specified in package.json and there is no chance that someone doesn't have the same version?

To be honest, I think it just wastes my time, mostly because of the conflicts that occur.

Comment: Not a waste of time. If you didn't commit yarn.lock you have absolutely no way of knowing that the code that's running on your machine during development is the same code that actually gets deployed (unless you commit `node_modules` to your repo and don't run a `yarn` step in CI). That's pretty dangerous and would definitely give a new spin to the phrase "it works on my machine"

Comment: But if my package.json contains "lodash": "5.5.5", isn't that mean that we have same releases?

Comment: Commit yarn.lock. I generally hate the term best practice, but this is one that’s really hard to argue against. There are security considerations as well involving sha in the lock file mentioned in my comment on the other answer. The other answer also rightfully points out that just because your dependency is pinned to a specific version (do you have CI enforcement that prevents ^ in your package.json?) in your package.json file, doesn’t mean that your dependency’s dependencies are (and they usually aren’t), which is where the lock file makes your builds reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

package.json does not guarantee that everyone will have same packages, unless you have specified the exact version in package.json, and the dependencies used have also done that in their package.json and their dependencies and so on. But that never happens which is why they came up with lock files.

> To be honest, I think it just wastes my time, mostly because of the conflicts that occur.

The conflicts happen because they don't have the same packages, if they had the same there would be no conflicts.

Example when you have v^1.0.0 in package json, it will install anything above v1 and below v2. The lockfile stores the exact version you installed,like v1.0.6, and the version of all the dependencies at that point of time. 3 months later installing without a lock file will install whatever new version matches the version pattern, and generate a new lock file that won't match the older one.

Comment: Not all members have same yarn versions, that's causing the change of yarn lock.

edit: Also like I said `considering that all versions are specified in package.json`, so we have versions without `^` mark

Comment: @vedran77 that’s a different issue. Solved with the [engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115897/vscode-github-desktop-pre-commit-hook-npx-command-not-found) keyword. Your developers don’t get to “choose what they want to install locally”, they have to play by the development environment required for your app. This is solvable with tools like nvm, asdf, or using an environment like docker. It’s not a problem of “yarn.lock” is annoying.

Comment: There are also potentially security implications by not committing yarn.lock because it contains sha’s of the packages being usdd. Those sha’s shouldn’t change. If devs are committing PRs with big changes to yarn.lock when they haven’t installed any dependencies, the PR shouldn’t be merged.

Comment: @vedran77 Even if you specify packageX:1.1.1 packageX may depend on packageY:^2.1.0, which may then depend on packageZ:^3.0.0 and so on. Check your lock file to get an idea of what all it contains.